# Не получается в браузере открыть .pdf файл с сервера nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Файл на сервере лежит тут `/var/www/dev/files/test.pdf`

По ссылке `http://www.site.ru/files/test.pdf` должен открыться pdf-файл в браузере (не для скачивания). Однако `http://www.site.ru/files/` выдаёт 403 ошибку, а нужная ссылка 404.

С этим вопросом я вышел в [Интернет](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), и даже try_files не помог.

В http ветке конфигурационного файла nginx.conf прописываю

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.site.ru;

  location = /files/test.pdf {
          # internal;
          # alias /var/www/dev/files;
          # types        { }
          # default_type  application/octet-stream;
          try_files       $uri    /var/www/dev/files/test.pdf;
  }
}
```

Пробовал различные варианты (закомментил решёткой) и ничего не помогло.
Пробовал и регулярки.

```
location ~ /files/\.(pdf)$ {...}
```

Вопрос: что не так? Может, в другом месте нужно что-то проверить.

**UPD:** Как оказалось, вся проблема была просто, потому что прописывал не в `/ngnix/sites-available/default`, а в `/ngnix/ngnix.conf`.

Comment: от какого пользователя запущен worker nginx-а? может ли этот пользователь читать директории и файл /var/www/dev/files/test.pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> По ссылке http://www.site.ru/files/test.pdf должен открыться pdf-файл
>   в браузере (не для скачивания)

Nginx Вам тут может помочь косвенно, по умолчанию Nginx только отдает статический контент, а уж как этот контент будет обработан в браузере - решает сам браузер, Google Chrome при получении типа application/pdf попытается его открыть во встроенном просмотрщике, MS IE этот файл просто предложить скачать и сохранить на диск т.к. у него нет встроенного просмотрщика PDF.

Например такой конфиг Nginx при открытии файда pdf заставит Chrome его скачать

```
location ~ ^/files/(.+\.pdf)$ {
  alias /var/www/dev/files/pdf/$1;
  add_header 'Content-Disposition' 'attachment; filename="$1"';
}
```

А такой конфиг заставит Chrome открыть pdf во встроенном просмотрщике, НО если встроенного просмотрщика нет, файл будет скачан, от этого вы никуда не денетесь.

```
location ~ ^/files/(.+\.pdf)$ {
  alias /var/www/dev/files/pdf/$1;
  add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/pdf';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать

```
location /files {
    alias /var/www/dev/files;
    expires 30d;
}
```